# How to get stream URLs from RTSP server

Tags: networking, rtsp

I would like to ask if it is possible to ask RTSP server, how many streams does it provide and what are their URL addresses. I have an IP camera from China. Unfortunately, I have not any documentation. There is the port 554 opened. I have tried tellneting to it, trying "DESCRIBE rtsp://my_ip_address/media.amp RTSP/1.0". It was answering with verison of RTSP server and error code. Trying to connect by VLC player (url /media.amp, /stream0, /0 etc) but without success. Is there any way, any command, how to ask the rtsp server for URLs which it is providing?

Comment: Search for 'rtsp' + cam company or vendor name in google. If you dont know vendor then open the cam and search serial numbers or stickers with info. Also you could to sniff packets in your cam network with whireshark to seek more info.

Comment: The camera is special prototype from China. Hardware and business company is different then firmware company, so it takes a long time till they search informations for me. Rtsp is opened on 554 and it is supported according to the datasheet, but there is no web interface or client software, which I could sniff via Wireshark...

Answer (score 0):

If you have no clue you can just test [popular IP cam RTSP addresses](http://www.soleratec.com/support/rtsp/rtsp_listing?camera_company=).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try ONVIF device manager to try and discover available RTSP feeds.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/